# How to make a horizontal 2-colored strip in a tablecell?

Tags: html, css, tablecell

I want to have a horizontal strip in a tablecell, such that the left side of it is one color (lets say blue) and the right one is a different one (lets say red). Now when i say left and right i don't mean exactly half, in fact the percentage of the strip that should be colored blue/red depends on some other data (that is easily accesible to any script files), and it can change for each tablecell. My dilemma is the following:

- I think i should do this with 2 divs in a tablecell. I could set their colors in css and set their width in a script. But i'm not sure how to align the divs in the tablecell to get a horizontal strip, so i need suggestions exactly for how the css for the divs should look like. Also perhaps i can use a span element instead of div? And finally maybe instead of all this, coloring an image of a strip is the best solution?

Comment: " the percentage of the strip that should be colored blue/red depends on some other data (that is easily accesible to any script files),"...post what you have tried and the some other "data" that you are talking about about which sould be accessible to ANY script files....

Comment: Inside a cell create the two span and set their width to 100% and height to ration in which you want. To put the one div at the bottom just put the top-margin in the bottom div to the % of the height of the above div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using only css with no divs.

Is this what you wanted?

```css
td {
  background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, red 15%, blue 15%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, red 15%, blue 15%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, red 15%, blue 15%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 15%, blue 15%); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>gradient make two colors in each cell</td><td>defined with CSS only</td></tr>
  <tr><td>more</td><td>data</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad I could help. By the way, you can put more colors to the gradient - just add more colors to brackets, you can try (to right, red 15%, blue 15%, blue 50%, green 50%).